# Ext Js add event to html element

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, dom-events

How can add onChange event to my html element which is rendered inside another component

```
  xtype: 'component',
                        html: {
                            html: '<input  type= "color" />'
                        },
                        itemId: 'colorPicker'
                    },
```

I want to add the following eventlistener to the input elelement:

```
   theInput.addEventListener("input", function() {

   <<Do something with theColor value here>>

    }, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case code is something like this:

```
html: '<input id=\'colorPickerBackground\' type=\'color\'></input>',
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(component) {
        var colorInput = component.getEl().down('#colorPickerBackground');
        colorInput.on('input', function() {
            console.log(colorInput.getValue());
        }); 
    }
}
```

[Simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15q5)